# Store Procedure Select into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I count the result of a table and pass into a Stored Procedure Variable?

```
DECLARE @totalrecs varchar
select count(id) from table1
```

I want the count record in the totalrecs variable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

like this

```
--will not count NULLS
select @totalrecs= count(id) from table1

--will count NULLS
select @totalrecs= count(*) from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @totalCount Int
Select @totalCount = count(*) 
From table1

Exec sp_DoSomething @Var = @totalCount
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select @totalrecs= count(id) from table1
```